# How to Configure a FTP Service where different user groups have different permissions for a single Directory

Tags: linux, ftp, ubuntu-12.04

(using Ubuntu 12.04)

I need to set up an FTP service where a specific set of users can write to the directory an another set can only read.

I'm thinking that it's hard to do for a single directory, because while I can set the directory's group bits to read only or read/write, I cannot associate the directory with two groups at two different security levels. Am I correct? How can I go about it if not.

I am thinking about creating two directories, one with the group bits set to read and write and associated with the write group, and the other with the bits set to read only and associated with the read group. Then hopefully there is a way to have the read directory link to files which were written to the 'write' group directory. Will that work, how can I go about it.

A detailed answer is best, but I can do the research and report back here if I can get some guidance as to what approach I should be taking and what technologies I should be learning about (e.g. linking or ACL's--which I've heard of but haven't used). I'd like to do this right and appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 0):

Linking directories **won't** work. If you do a symlink, the rights of the symlink won't matter, just the rights of the original directory. Hardlinking directories is usually not permitted by the OS.

#### First solution:

Just leave the OS file system out of it, and use an FTP server that has the ability to restrict users to read-only or write-only. `ncftpd` springs to mind.

#### Second solution:

Is it important that these files not be readable by anyone other than group 2? If that is not important, then the easiest way would be to set the directory as readable for other but only writable for group.

#### Third solution (the crappiest one, IMO)

Another method would be to have two separate directories, one for each group, and have a cron job run every 5 minutes or so to copy (or move) the files from each directory.

Comment: Thank you. I like the second solution better than the 1st but would prefer to restrict the 'other' user, though I'm not entirely sure why, lol. I'm looking into ACL's. There just has to be a more general solution. Because, security at the application level is just to specific to keep track of and maintain and while the second solution will work for me here, it wont at all help when read permission is sensitive or when I'd want to divide w vs x permissions.

Comment: If you want that kind of fine grained permissions, ACLs is definitely the way to go.